# What's the best way to SSH to machines on the local network?

Tags: networking, ssh

I have 2 computers, one that I use and one for the kids. I want to be able to ssh into their computer to control it (like to shut it down etc) but am curious the best way to do this. We both are in the same house and share the same internet connection.

What would be the best way to do this? From research, I read to install openssh-server on the remote computer but am stumped what to use for the hostname when trying to connect. Usually for VPS's it's the external IP but since we both share a wifi connection would it be the hardware IP? Should we be interfacing directly by LAN or by going through the internet?

Comment: being able to ssh into your kids machines is a serious breach of privacy. You should set rules and turn it off manually or set a timer for shut down times. I disapprove. If my parents could ssh into my machine I'd feel violated.

Comment: At what age do children begin to have "privacy"? :-)

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Run:

```
avahi-browse -tl _workstation._tcp
```

To get a list of Ubuntu workstations in the local network, then you can connect to them by running:

```
ssh <username>@<computer-name>.local
```

Comment: Note: for `avahi-browse`, you'll need to install the `avahi-utils` package (which will also pull in `avahi-daemon`, the service providing the .local addressability).

Comment: @Piskvor Good point. This package is already installed by default in Ubuntu Desktop, but I don't know about other flavors (kubuntu, lubuntu, etc). If it isn't installed just run `sudo apt-get install avahi-utils`.

Comment: so would it be necessary to setup an ssh server or does e.g. ubuntu 14.04 run one by default?

Comment: @tobi SSH server is not installed by default. You have to install it.

Comment: the list seems empty after I run `avahi`. Both computers are connected to the same router

Answer (score 20):

You can use the IP address to ssh into the kid's computer.
If you want to use the computer name, edit your /etc/hosts file to include the computer name.

```
192.168.1.104  dad
192.168.1.105  kids
```

Comment: You need to point out that the IPs need to be statically assigned to the computers.

Comment: You can enable `ssh`ing by name without editing the hosts file by naming hosts in `~/.ssh/config`: http://www.howtogeek.com/75007/stupid-geek-tricks-use-your-ssh-config-file-to-create-aliases-for-hosts/

Comment: @NathanLong - Nice tip! though one could argue having it in hosts file lets one access any service (if that is desired).

Answer (score 15):

Before doing `ssh`, check for ssh client and server. If you don't have these services, install them with the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-client

sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

If you have already installed them, just do:

```
ssh username@ipaddress
```

and enter the connecting device login password.

- Example :

  ```
  ssh prem@192.168.1.145

  prem@192.168.1.145's password:********
  ```

If you get any error like : `Permission denied, please try again.`, please check twice for Username and IP.

Answer (score 8):

I use the file ~/.ssh/config which ssh parses automatically, here is an example:

```
Host *
ControlMaster auto
ControlPath /tmp/%r@%h:%p

KeepAlive yes 
ServerAliveInterval 60
ServerAliveCountMax 10
ControlPersist 1h

Host server1
        User user1
        HostName server1-web.example.org

Host server2
        User user2
        HostName server2-db.example.org
        Compression yes
        IdentityFile /home/user/.ssh/different_key.pem
```

Note that you can use any (clientside) variable in this file and either set it globally or per server.

Comment: Then how does one configure the DNS facility of a home Internet gateway appliance to associate `server1-web.example.org` and `server2-db.example.org` with the respective servers?

Answer (score 6):

1. You can ssh directly to a local IP provided that your LAN uses static IPs, for example
   `ssh someuser@192.168.1.2`
2. You can edit hosts file in both computers, as mentioned by Ed Manet in his [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/305231/12218). That way you can then ssh using computer's hostname, that is `ssh someuser@some_hostname`
3. You can setup a local DNS server to resolve your LAN's hosts. This way you will be able to ssh using the computer's hostname as in option 2 but with additional benefit  the avoidance of editing every hosts file, by pointing your DNS server in Ubuntu's network settings.

[DNSMasq](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dnsmasq) is pretty good DNS server easy to setup.
Another option is [BIND](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIND).

Answer (score 4):

Use the local LAN IP address. The alternate approach requires some port to be open to the Internet, to allow you to login.

Also, you would need port mapping (on the router). Using your 'public' IP address (on the router) as a target will **not** connect to either of your two PCs.

---

The simplest way is to permanently assign each IP address (for your 2 computers) on the router. Then simply connect to that IP address.

If you want to get clever (later), set up a server and start using a local DNS service to assign meaningful names to each device. *Not really worth the trouble for only 2 PCs.*

Comment: Note: many decent home routers nowadays will read the workstations' hostnames during IP address assignment, and will resolve it for local DNS. Alas, this is not a universal feature just yet.

Answer (score 2):

If you are sharing the same internet connection you are most likely behind the same wifi router.
So you connect directly to your kids computer:

```
ssh <IP-address>
```

or:

```
ssh <user-name>@<IP-address>
```

Obviously this works better if the kids computer has static IP address. Otherwise you always need to check what the IP is. Most routers have an option to assign static (always the same) IP to chosen devices. Some routers also have an option to assign host name to certain device - then for any device in the same network address "kids" would mean the same. If you assign host names with /etc/hosts file the host name is only known to that computer where that host file is. Also that assumes that kids computer has static IP address.

You can set static IP to kids computer also in that machine but I advice setup where network settings are done in the router. One point of control - easier to manage.
If something is unclear, leave a comment and I will expand my answer.

Comment: I've tried Your suggestion, but got an error: `ssh: connect to host xxx.xxx.x.xx port 22: connection refused` - is there any additional configuration neccessary?

Comment: There needs to be ssh server running on that machine and no firewall blocking it and so forth. It could be that ssh has been configured to expect connections on some other port in which case it is possible to user -p flag to use something else than the default port (22).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the IP address in place of a hostname or assign a custom host name in your `/etc/hosts` file.

To get the IP on the kid's computer: on the network menu see "Connection Information" **or** run `ifconfig` on the commandline (these have to be done on the kid's computer).

Your wifi router assigns these IP addresses and you should be able to configure it to keep specific IP addresses for the computers they are currently assigned to. (Otherwise the IP's may change from time to time).