# How to connect to a laptop running Ubuntu on the same home wireless network?

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, ssh, connection

I am running Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS 64-bit on both of my laptops and they are both connected to the same home Wi-Fi at the moment.

I want to connect to the other computer via one of the computers, say through `SSH`, how can I do so? What credentials should I know about both computers and which command should I use?

My intention is not simple file sharing and I want some other solution than Teamviewer etc. although X-Windows forwarding would be nice. I appreciate your assistance in this matter.

**Edit:** When I try SSHing I got the following on the prompt:

```
VesnogXPS:~$ ssh ongun@192.168.1.22
ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.22 port 22: Connection refused
```

**Edit2:** The above problem is resolved but now it cannot read the .bashrc on the connected computer the permissions for the file is as follows:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 ongun ongun 3567 Jan  4 01:06 .bashrc
```

The error I get is as follows and it is present in only when connecting from A to B not while connecting from B to A:

```
ongun@192.168.1.20's password: 
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-45-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

Last login: Thu Feb 19 18:52:54 2015 from 192.168.1.22
-bash: /home/ongun/.bashrc: Permission denied
```

The contents of the ~/.profile on the problematic laptop is:

```
# ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files for examples.
# the files are located in the bash-doc package.

# the default umask is set in /etc/profile; for setting the umask
# for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package.
#umask 022

# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    "$HOME/.bashrc"
    PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/i386-linux:$PATH; export PATH 
    MANPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/doc/man:$MANPATH; export MANPATH         INFOPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/doc/info:$INFOPATH; export INFOPATH
    fi
fi
```

Figured the problem out it was not sourcing the `.bashrc` I did change the line after the **second if** as follows:
. "$HOME/.bashrc"

Now everything works perfectly, but I have one more question, why did it use to work for the terminal emulator on the local machine but not SSH itself? I am asking this since both are interactive login shells.

Comment: @user68186 The intention is not file sharing only.

Comment: @user68186 Thanks for now I would like to go with `SSH` but I wanted for command-line interface but I also wanted to know the other options possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first you need to know the IP addresses (try `ifconfig` or `ip addr show` or any other method) of the laptops lets say Laptop A's IP is "192.168.1.4" and Laptop B's IP is "192.168.1.5". To do `ssh` from A to B and vice versa you need to install the ssh server on both laptops by following command:

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

As client is automatically installed by default you now should be able to `ssh` either directions by:

```
ssh username@192.168.1.4 ##From B to A
ssh username@192.168.1.4 ##From A to B
```

Here "username" is any user of "192.168.1.4/192.168.1.5" as whom you are logging in.

If you want `ssh` X11 forwarding try this:

```
ssh -Y username@192.168.1.4
ssh -Y username@192.168.1.5
```

Read [manpage of ssh](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/dapper/man1/ssh.1.html) to get more idea.

**EDIT:** As "Rmano" suggested in the comment, you can check for "DHCP preallocation". Have a look at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/305229/whats-the-best-way-to-ssh-to-machines-on-the-local-network) and [this](http://pclosmag.com/html/Issues/201102/page18.html).

**Answer to the EDIT:** I think you have not installed `openssh-server` on 192.168.1.22 leading to the error connection refused. You can check which tcp ports of 192.168.1.11 are in listening state for connections by doing

`netstat -tlpn`

from 192.168.1.22 and then look for port 22 by `netstat -tlpn | grep 22`. You can also check this from 192.168.1.11:

```
nmap -PN 192.168.1.22
```

**Answer to the 2nd EDIT**: The problem is that in your `~/.profile` instead of sourcing the `~/.bashrc` file by `. $HOME/.bashrc` it is doing `"$HOME/.bashrc"`. The code snippet should be:

```
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
        . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi
```

Comment: It is a good idea to configure your router so that the two laptops have the same IP address always. Most (if not all) routers allow this; it is called "DHCP preallocation" or similar jargon (see the instruction for your router). After that, all is easy --- see for example http://askubuntu.com/questions/305229/whats-the-best-way-to-ssh-to-machines-on-the-local-network and http://pclosmag.com/html/Issues/201102/page18.html

Comment: @Rmano: Good point..adding..

Comment: The usernames are the same on both laptops, can I omit them? And one more question: If I did not have prior access to laptops how can I obtain their local IP? Can I obtain them through the web interface of the router, is there any other method?

Comment: @Vesnog: you don't need to omit them, same username is alright.

Comment: Oh by the way I get the following error in the edit.

Comment: @Vesnog: I think you have not installed `openssh-server` on 192.168.1.22 leading to `connection refused`. You can check which tcp ports of 192.168.1.11 are listening for connections by doing `netstat -tlpn` from 192.168.1.22. Check for port 22.

Comment: @Vesnog: It seems that your subnet is 192.168.1.0/24, you can use `nmap -sP 192.168.1.0/24` to find out all other live hosts in the subnet.

Comment: @heemayl Is plain `ssh` not enough for this? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: This works but when it logs in it cannot read the `.bashrc` on the other computer returning permission denied. Why is it so?

Comment: @Vesnog: If you do `sudo apt-get install ssh`, that will work too as it will install openssh server and client. Do you mean when you ssh into B from A, you can't read the `~/.bashrc` in B? If that is the case then its ridiculous, unless you change something beforehand this should not happen, could you please check the permission of the file.

Comment: @heemayl Yeah that is exactly the case as I can confirm by querying the aliases since this is a login shell. I am now checking the permissions. The permissions are as in the edit on both computer A and computer B.

Comment: Do a `ls -l ~/.bashrc` and post the output..

Comment: @heemayl Did that and they are the same on both computers, please see the edit.

Comment: @Vesnog: The permissions look Ok. Your ~/.profile, /etc/profile is sourced when entering a login-interactive shell like ssh provide you with, which in turn will source the ~/.bashrc and /etc/bash.bashrc too along with any other scripts in /etc/profile.d/. I am guessing there is something wrong in any of these. Please check for anything suspicious in these files.

Comment: @heemayl Thanks shall I also check the permissions for these?

Comment: @Vesnog: You can but i strongly thinking there is some wrong line in any of these files. Does the shell prompt comes up or just stuck in the permission issue forever?

Comment: @heemayl The prompt comes up the CLI is not stuck but for example the aliases and other customization do not work since .bashrc is not sourced.

Comment: @Vesnog: I see, try `source ~/.profile`

Comment: @heemayl Chat did not work should I try it from after logging in via SSH? Tried that way and I get the same error.

Comment: @heemayl Solved the problem a `.` (dot) was missing in front of `.bashrc` path anyways why did it use to work for terminal emulator but not SSH now it is questioning me.

Comment: @Vesnog: I was waiting for you in the chat, i just checked in here some time ago and found the ~/.profile entry. Seems we have found it at the same time. Check my 2nd edit. Weird that i did not get any notification of your last comment, otherwise it would be faster ;)

Comment: @heemayl I could not log into chat thanks for your help and time I appreciate it. By the way is there any difference between SSH interactive login shell and terminal emulator login shell? Everything I defined in `.bashrc` worked flawlessly locally, that is why I am asking.

Comment: Yes, there are differences. While doing `ssh` you are getting a login-interactive shell whereas when you are opening the terminal from GUI you are opening a non-login-interactive shell. Check this http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38175/difference-between-login-shell-and-non-login-shell

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21304/discussion-on-answer-by-heemayl-how-to-connect-to-a-laptop-running-ubuntu-on-the).