# SSH from Ubuntu to Lubuntu on a local network

Tags: networking, lubuntu, ssh

I want to SSH from my laptop to a device on my local network running Lubuntu. I'm trying to use the method described in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/305241/135947).

To get a list of Ubuntu:

```
avahi-browse -tl _workstation._tcp
```

How should I modify the command to show my Lubuntu device, or should I expect it to work as is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your lubuntu machine run ifconfig -a to find the ipaddress assuming you don't recall the host name. Then open a terminal on your Ubuntu machine and type **ssh user@ipaddress(or host name)** and then type in the password for the user. Alternatively you can setup a private key for your Ubuntu machine and upload the public key to your lubuntu machine, eliminating the need for entering a password.

1. ssh-keygen
2. Leave pass phrase blank or enter one. Entering one is more secure.
3. ssh-copy-id **user@ipaddress**
4. Enter password for user
5. Enter pass phrase if created

From then on, you will only need to type **ssh user@ipaddress** to log on to your server. You can research ssh config file to make it even simpler if you prefer. Hope this helps.

If not... What error or problem are you actually having? Detail is everything.